# How to solve the start Github Desktop (win10) error: could not lock config file, permission denied

Tags: github

Recently, my Github Desktop (Win10) start to show the following warning everytime when I start my Github Desktop.

**WARNING:** error running C:\Users\li58\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.6.0\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin\git.exe 'config' '--global' '--replace-all' 'filter.lfs.clean' 'git-lfs clean -- %f': 'warning: unable to access 'C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig': Permission denied
error: could not lock config file C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig: Permission denied' 'exit status 255'
Run `git lfs install --force` to reset git config.

These are what I have tried and didn't solved the problem:

- I have done the `git lfs install --force`. It shows "Git LFS initialized". But I still see this error every time.
- I have also reinstalled github and problem still exist...
- I have tried `git config --system --unset credential.helper` in the gitBash which was opened as admin.

Has anyone ever had the same problem? Could anyone help, please? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Posting for anybody looking as this is a couple of years old. I had a similar error to this. Every time I tried to clone or commit I was getting something like:

Could not create directory '/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh' (Permission denied). Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.ssh/known_hosts). git@XXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

So basically, whenever my PC rebooted, GIT kept trying to look in c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile for config and ssh settings.

I could not make any modifications to my global .gitconfig file either, as Windows could not lock the file.

I reinstalled GIT which would fix the issue temporarily, but when I rebooted, the issues would return.

Eventually I found I had a 'HOME' system variable set in Windows environment variables. It seemed that git was looking at this and trying to use c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile for everything.

Deleted the HOME variable, rebooted, and it fixed the problem.